помогите мне заставить If распознать буквы которые человек уже в рабочем коде
import time
import random 

formul = int(input("какую формулу вам надо?:"))

if formul (str("S")):
    V = int(input("введите скорость км/час"))


Рабочий код:
formul = input("Какую формулу вам надо?:")

if formul == "S":
    v = int(input("Введите скорость км/час"))


В переменную formul Вы считываете строку-название, поэтому преобразование в число (int) не нужно (а для считывания скорости v требуется).

Для работы оператора if требуется выражение, которое возвращает булево значение. В Вашем случае для этого требуется использовать оператор сравнения ==


Это в принципе минимальная база языка программирования. Поэтому, если у Вас трудности с такими вопросами, то можно пройти какой-нибудь курс.
